# Unable to assign [undefined] to QUrl

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qabstractlistmodel

I have a model and a qml.

Model.cpp:

```
Model::Model(QObject *parent): QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

void Model::addIcon(const QString &iconName, const QString &iconPath)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    if(!indexMap.contains(iconName)) {
        paths.append(iconPath);
        indexMap.insert(iconName,paths.indexOf(iconPath));
    }
    else {

        //Update the icon for the designated icon
        paths[indexMap.value(iconName)] = iconPath;
        QModelIndex index = createIndex(indexMap.value(iconName),1);
        emit dataChanged(index,index);
    }

    endInsertRows();
}

QVariant Model::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= indexMap.count())
        return QVariant();

    return paths.at(index.row());
}

int Model::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent)
    return paths.count();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> Model::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[PathRole] = "iconImage";
    return roles;
}
```

Model.h

```
class Model : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    enum MyRoles {
        PathRole = Qt::UserRole + 1
    };
    Q_ENUM(MyRoles)


    explicit Model(QObject *parent = 0);


    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

    void addIcon(const QString &iconName, const QString &iconPath);

private:
    QList<QString> paths;
    QMap<QString,int> indexMap;

};
```

Wrapper:

Q_PROPERTY(MyModel* modelProperty READ getModel NOTIFY modelChanged)

Qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Rectangle{
width:100
height:30

    ListView{
        id:icons

        property alias myModel: myService.modelProperty

        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.rightMargin: 20

        model: myModel

        delegate: Image{source: iconImage}
    }
}
```

When I set the icon for the first time, it gives me no error message. Put after the first assignment I get the error "unable to assign [undefined] to QUrl".

I add the new icon path with addIcon method in the model.

Do you have any idea why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jiu I added the header file and I forgot to mentioned that, icon paths are updated correctly. I mean I just get a warning.

Comment: @huckfin  What values ​​does iconPath take?

Comment: @eyllanesc it just takes the path of the icon as QString. For example: qrc:/warningIcon

Comment: @huckfin show MyService.h please

Comment: @eyllanesc it does no more than just calling the addIcon() function by passing the path string of the icon. However i have  a wrapper which could be relevant and i've just added it to the post.

Comment: @huckfin modelProperty is a Q_PROPERTY?

Comment: Are you trying to show a list of icons(`paths`) which added by `addIcon`?

Comment: @Jiu I'm trying to add an icon then update its image. It works correctly except i get the mentioned warning.

Comment: @huckfin What does *first assignment I* mean?

Comment: @eyllanesc Here is the scenario: As program started, there is no icon. When i clicked a button it calls addIcon and puts the icon there, this is the first assignment. Then, I click another button and the same icon's image is changed. This is where i get the warning.

Comment: @huckfin 
With what it shows I can not reproduce your problem, please take the time and provide a real [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning means you returned invalid value from `data`.

```
#include <QAbstractListModel>

#define Invalid -1

class Model : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    struct Icon {
        QString name;
        QString path;
    };
    Q_INVOKABLE void add(QString name, QString path) {
        add({name, path});
    }
    void add(const Icon& icon) {
        const int& i = find(icon.name);
        if(i != Invalid) {
            mIconPaths[i].path = icon.path;
            emit dataChanged(index(i), index(i)); // Do not add beginInsertRows
        } else {
            beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
            mIconPaths.push_back(icon);
            endInsertRows();
        }
    }

    int find(const QString& name) {
        for(int i = 0; i < mIconPaths.size(); i++)
            if(mIconPaths[i].name == name)
                return i;
        return Invalid;
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        Q_UNUSED(role)
        if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= rowCount())
            return QVariant();
        return mIconPaths.at(index.row()).path;
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const
    {
        Q_UNUSED(parent)
        return mIconPaths.count();
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const
    {
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        roles[0] = "icon";
        return roles;
    }

private:
    QList<Icon> mIconPaths;
};
```

Test QML:

```
Window
{
    visible: true
    height: 640
    width: 480

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: myModel
        delegate: Text{
            text: icon
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            myModel.add("test", "test")
            myModel.add("test", "modified")
            myModel.add("test2", "added")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works but i want to understand what was wrong with my code. Is it the Q_INVOKABLE or the dataChanged signal that made it work?

Comment: @huckfin beginInsertRows & dataChanged are different actions. You did both when data modification. beginInsertRows tells ListView was inserted, dataChanged tells ListView was modified.

Comment: ok, then what i did was to both try to add and modify. Thanks again for clarification.

Comment: @huckfin And another problem, QAbstractListModel is a list, so why don't use the list to store the data instead of the map. That makes me confused about the question at first.

Comment: Q_INVOKABLE only for demonstration.

Comment: Actually first i was planning to use it for different purpose. The logic in the code I wrote is taking the index from the map variable and uses it in the paths list. Sorry for the inconvenience I should have just removed that.